# Formatting the printout of Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, formatting

I am building a program to track my employees. I have a CSV where I keep track of information. I'm trying to loop through and print out the rows of employees that dont have an end_date - i.e. those that are still working.
I have been able to get the correct rows to print, but the formatting is not how I'm hoping, which is in rows.
Here is an example of my csv:

```
csv = [employee_id,name,address,Phone,date_of_birth,job_title,start_date,end_date
      1,Arya,New York,1234567890,1/1/1970,lecturer,1/1/2021,10/20/2022
      2,Terri,New York,25151521,010109,Nurse,10/10/2022,
      42,Bill,New York,2314,09/10/1994,Teacher,10/14/2022,
      48,Steve,New York,454554,08/10/1994,Teacher,02/25/2022,
      9,Stephen,New York,526415252,10/08/1994,Teacher,10/15/2022,N/A]
```

here is the program that im running:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('employees.csv')

print()
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    if ((len(str(row['end_date'])) <= 3)):
        print(df2.loc[index])
    else:
        continue
print()
```

This print out looks like this for each line (multiples of the below):

```
employee_id             8
name                 Bill
address          New York
phone               25235
date_of_birth      081019
job_title        Engineer
start_date         081019
end_date              NaN
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

however, i want the print out to look like the beginning csv, but only showing the rows for people without values in the 'end_date' column like this:

```
[employee_id,name,address,Phone,date_of_birth,job_title,start_date,end_date
2,Terri,New York,25151521,010109,Nurse,10/10/2022,
42,Bill,New York,2314,09/10/1994,Teacher,10/14/2022,
48,Steve,New York,454554,08/10/1994,Teacher,02/25/2022,
```

I dont want use df.drop becaues I want to keep a record of everyone.

Comment: You could replace the whole thing in between print() with df2[ df2 ["end_date"] <= 3 ]

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = {'employee_id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 42, 3: 48, 4: 9}, 'name': {0: 'Arya', 1: 'Terri', 2: 'Bill', 3: 'Steve', 4: 'Stephen'}, 'address': {0: 'New York', 1: 'New York', 2: 'New York', 3: 'New York', 4: 'New York'}, 'Phone': {0: '1234567890', 1: '25151521', 2: '2314', 3: '454554', 4: '526415252'}, 'date_of_birth': {0: '1/1/1970', 1: '010109', 2: '09/10/1994', 3: '08/10/1994', 4: '10/08/1994'}, 'job_title': {0: 'lecturer', 1: 'Nurse', 2: 'Teacher', 3: 'Teacher', 4: 'Teacher'}, 'start_date': {0: '1/1/2021', 1: '10/10/2022', 2: '10/14/2022', 3: '02/25/2022', 4: '10/15/2022'}, 'end_date': {0: '10/20/2022', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: 'N/A'}}

df['end_date'] = df['end_date'].replace(['N/A',''], np.nan)

#prints only rows with null values in end_date
df[df['end_date'].isna()]
```

Also, a simpler way to get your vertical printout for each employee:

```
for e in df['employee_id']:
    df[df['employee_id']==e].transpose()


#output
employee_id             1
name                 Arya
address          New York
Phone          1234567890
date_of_birth    1/1/1970
job_title        lecturer
start_date       1/1/2021
end_date       10/20/2022
```